# Syncing two mongodb's

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Im trying to figure out how to solve following use case with usage of mongodb.

There is a main server, where users can upload/edit/... contents. Sometimes the users want to work independently of the main, so they get a defined set of entries of mongodb of the main server and can deploy own local environment. But after some time, they want to get an update for entries from main server and/or submit their own updates or new insertions

Is there any out of box solution for that? I thought that the standard replica sets can be used, but the documentation is so sparse, so i cant really understand if it can work, if users are e.g. 1 month offline

Comment: replica sets can not be used for this. You must send writes to the primary node. If you don't have connection to the primary, you can't write.

Comment: In short, mongodb can't be used for this. CouchDB, I heard, is designed for precisely this scenario.